# How do I drag objects on the screen using `OnMouseDrag`?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Tried doing 2D and 3D. I want the player to click and drag objects to stack them. I tried copying and pasting code from a video and it still didn't work.

UPDATE! Now it kinda works but it teleports the object far off the screen. I want the player to be able to smoothly click and drag the object.

The code as of now:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DragObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float deltax, deltay;


    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        deltax = 1f;//Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x - transform.position.x;
        deltay = 1f; //Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y - transform.position.y;
    }

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector2 currentTouchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = new Vector2((Input.mousePosition).x - deltax, (Input.mousePosition.y) - deltay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi games247! Welcome to StackOverflow. You know, I don't think any of us here on StackOverflow has our crystal ball with us today? Care to clarify more on what you're talking about? Show us your code, show us your error message. I can sense a few downvotes on their way. Edit your question following this guideline: [How To Ask A Question On StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear at all what exact problem is for you, you obviously need to give more info and describe your issue better. But I'll try to help as I can.

To get mouse position you need to use:

```
Input.mousePosition
```

If you need mouse position in 2d coordinates you can use this:

```
Vector2 currentTouchPos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
```

Comment: @games247 You still aren't using the `currentTouchPos` when setting the objects position. `Input.mousePosition` comes in **pixel** coordinates so it's probably simply too huge. Try `transform.position = currentTouchPos - new 
 Vector2(deltax, deltay);`

Comment: If Asker is using a perspective camera, this won't work because `currentTouchPos` will always be the x and y position of the camera.

Answer (score 1):

This method works regardless of your camera type or how the camera moves between frames

First, when the object is first clicked, get the plane at the object's position perpendicular to the direction of the camera:

```
Plane dragPlane = new Plane(Camera.main.transform.forward, transform.position);
```

Then, get the ray coming out of the camera from where the mouse is:

```
Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
```

Find out where that ray intersects using [`Plane.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html):

```
float enter = 0.0f;
if (dragPlane.Raycast(camRay, out enter)) 
{
    Vector3 fingerPosition = camRay.GetPoint(enter);
```

This gives you a position in world space, which is where you can consider the finger to currently be at. Just put the object there:

```
transform.position = fingerPosition;
```

Altogether it might look like this:

```
void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Plane dragPlane = new Plane(Camera.main.transform.forward, transform.position);
    Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    float enter = 0.0f;
    if (dragPlane.Raycast(camRay, out enter)) 
    {
        Vector3 fingerPosition = camRay.GetPoint(enter);
        transform.position = fingerPosition;
    }
}
```

No `OnMouseDown` necessary.

An alternative is to keep track of how `fingerPosition` changes over time, and [`Translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) the transform based on that. Keeping as much math as possible in world units makes it easy:

```
Vector3 prevFingerPosition = Vector3.zero;

// Same code as before but we use it in different places so it goes in its own method.
// If the Raycast fails, return a decent guess.
private Vector3 GetMouseOnPositionInWorldSpace() 
{
    Plane dragPlane = new Plane(Camera.main.transform.forward, transform.position);
    Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    float enter = 0.0f;
    if (dragPlane.Raycast(camRay, out enter))
    {
        return camRay.GetPoint(enter);
    }

    return prevFingerPosition;
}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    prevFingerPosition = GetMouseOnPositionInWorldSpace();
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 fingerPosition = GetMouseOnPositionInWorldSpace();
    transform.Translate(fingerPosition-prevFingerPosition);
    prevFingerPosition = fingerPosition;
}
```

There is an issue behind using `OnMouseDrag` to handle dragging objects around is that if the cursor moves too quickly, it can move off the object in the span of a single frame, and it will "drop" the object.

If that's not desirable, you might want to set a `bool` to be `true` in `OnMouseDown` that remembers that the object was clicked and a move the logic out of `OnMouseDrag` and into `Update` where it can do its thing if that `bool` is `true`. And when the mouse is released, set that `bool` back to `false`.